# How to stop maintaining scroll position during ajax timer asynchronous postback when user manually changed the scroll position?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am using a multi-line text box as a chat window by using asynchronous postback. I was able to maintain the scroll position, but when a user is reading the chat messages, the text box automatically scrolls to the very bottom. I am able to maintain the position the user is at or make it scroll automatically down. However, I want to do both.

Here is my code:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler); 
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) { 
  xPos = $get('txtChatBox').scrollLeft; 
  yPos = $get('txtChatBox').scrollTop; 
  zpos =$get('txtChatBox').scrollHeight; 
} 

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) { 
  $get('txtChatBox').scrollLeft = xPos + 1; 
  $get('txtChatBox').scrollTop = yPos + 1; 
  $get('txtChatBox').scrollTop =zpos+1; 
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should include the code you are using, and be specific about which part has the issue.

Comment: Delete, make it part of the question and format it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/scroll) to detect whether the user has manually scrolled away.

```
var xPos, yPos, hasScrolled, timer, box = $get('txtChatBox');
box.onscroll = function(e) {
  hasScrolled = true;
  /* if you want to invalidate the flag after the user has not scrolled
     for a certain period, use
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    hasScrolled = false;
  }, 60000) // 1 min for example
  */
};
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) { 
  xPos = box.scrollLeft; 
  yPos = box.scrollTop;
  zPos = box.scrollHeight;
  hasScrolled = false;
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
  if (!hasScrolled) {
    box.scrollLeft = xPos + 1; 
    box.scrollTop = zPos+1;
  }
}
```

Or you just compare the stored scrollTop (`yPos`) to the current one, to detect whether the user scrolled away (and not back):

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
  if (box.scrollTop == yPos) {
    box.scrollLeft = xPos + 1; 
    yPos = box.scrollTop = zPos+1;
  }
}
```